# search and facet api tables dropped during module updates

Tags: 7, drush, search

We recently added search-api and facet-api functionality to work with a new Drupal 7 view, and now whenever certain module updates are performed using Drush, one or more of the following tables are found to be corrupt or missing:

> search_api_db_00_facet,
>   search_api_db_00_facet_field_facetname,
>   search_api_db_00_facet_text,
>   search_api_db_00_search,
>   search_api_db_00_search_text,
>   search_api_db_00_facet,
>   search_api_db_00_facet_field_facetname,
>   search_api_db_00_facet_text,
>   search_api_db_00_facet_text_1,
>   search_api_db_00_search,
>   search_api_index.sql,
>   search_api_server.sql

After these tables are restored from backup all is well again. We are using MyISAM table format in the database. No error message displays in the Drupal log until after this has occured. Search module is being used for whole site, while search-api is used for one application. Website is medium sized. The application created by content type and view contains 44,000 nodes. Is this a MySQL problem, such as a need to convert to INNODB, a search-api issue, or a facet-api issue? This doesn't seem to be a common occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved, thanks to an insight rocketeerbkw provided about the `drush up` process. I changed my user umask setting to 022 in .bashrc to be more permissive for files that my account creates on the server. This completely resolved the database table dropping issue. Before I changed the umask, I had been running drush using my normal user account with a private umask setting, and when drush downloaded new files for updates, the resulting strict permissions broke any cache rebuilds that might have been involved and also on occasion broke the database connectivity. This was neither a MySQL nor drush issue.